# Install "hunchentoot" error?

Tags: hunchentoot, quicklisp

I want to install hunchentoot on my freebsd box, but quicklisp reports error:

```
(ql:quickload "hunchentoot")
To load "hunchentoot":
 Load 3 ASDF systems:
 rfc2388 trivial-backtrace usocket
Install 15 Quicklisp releases:
alexandria babel bordeaux-threads cffi chunga 
cl+ssl cl-base64 cl-fad cl-ppcre flexi-streams 
hunchentoot md5 trivial-features trivial-garbage 
trivial-gray-streams
```

*** - Header missing magic values 1F,8B (got 3C,21 instead)!
The following restarts are available:
ABORT          :R1      Give up on "hunchentoot"

ABORT Break 1 [2]> :i

## :  standard object

type: QL-GUNZIPPER::GZIP-DECOMPRESSION-ERROR
0 [$FORMAT-CONTROL]:  "Header missing magic values ~2,'0X,~2,'0X (got ~2,'0X,~2,'0X instead)!"
1 [$FORMAT-ARGUMENTS]:  (31 139 60 33)         :R2      Abort main loopnter code here

How to fix it ? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the files Quicklisp has downloaded are not valid; they don't start with the expected GZIP file header. Instead, they start with `<!...` which looks very much like HTML. Do you have a proxy involved on your network? If so, try this:

```
(setf (ql-config:config-value "proxy-url") "http://your.proxy.url:xyz/")
```

Answer (score -1):

The "hunchentoot" can be installed on my archlinux box now. But the "uffi" cannot be installed:

```
(ql:quickload "uffi") 
To load " uffi":
Install 1 Quicklisp release:
uffi
; Fetching #<URL "http://beta.quicklisp.org/archive/uffi/2010-11-07/uffi-20101107-git.tgz">
; 175.27KB
==================================================
179,479 bytes in 10.53 seconds (16.64KB/sec)
; Loading "uffi"

*** - Component "uffi" not found
```

I donot understand why the quicklisp has so many problems !